# CentOS 7: Job for httpd.service failed

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, vps

I have a CentOS 7 VPS where I am trying to install virtual host following the instruction from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-7.

I have completed step five of this tutorial. Then when I try to restart apache I failed:

```
$ sudo apachectl restart
[sudo] password for student01: 
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
$ sudo systemctl status httpd.service -l
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since বুধ 2018-04-11 14:29:55 +06; 4min 13s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 11116 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 11115 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 11115 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

এপ্রি 11 14:29:55 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
এপ্রি 11 14:29:55 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
এপ্রি 11 14:29:55 localhost.localdomain kill[11116]: kill: cannot find process ""
এপ্রি 11 14:29:55 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
এপ্রি 11 14:29:55 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
এপ্রি 11 14:29:55 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
এপ্রি 11 14:29:55 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

Now, What can I do?

**Edit**
/var/log/httpd/error_log

```
[Sun Apr 08 03:23:02.040472 2018] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 20339] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Apr 08 03:23:02.041376 2018] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 20339] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Apr 08 03:23:02.094944 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20339] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.4.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Apr 08 03:23:02.094956 2018] [core:notice] [pid 20339] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sun Apr 08 05:35:00.720095 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 30351] [client 66.102.6.114:59512] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Sun Apr 08 09:42:05.222459 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 30347] [client 52.34.24.33:31614] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Sun Apr 08 11:06:56.497939 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 30790] [client 54.145.188.132:22136] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Sun Apr 08 14:13:12.731870 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 32239] [client 185.198.167.29:51750] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Sun Apr 08 19:06:12.521882 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 30348] [client 180.234.211.210:57961] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Sun Apr 08 19:06:15.004820 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 30790] [client 159.203.81.93:36934] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive, referer: http://csedu.cf/noindex/css/open-sans.css
[Sun Apr 08 21:20:59.825782 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 1338] [client 66.102.6.114:52716] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Apr 09 00:25:17.935192 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 30348] [client 178.73.215.171:58579] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Apr 09 02:50:04.593613 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 30351] [client 141.8.142.139:50790] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Apr 09 03:17:12.517868 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 30347] [client 222.186.173.47:3128] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Apr 09 04:10:37.253275 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 31639] [client 164.132.91.1:38580] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Apr 09 05:38:34.833406 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 30350] [client 66.249.70.23:49821] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Apr 09 05:42:25.297309 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 30790] [client 66.102.6.118:49432] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Apr 09 08:37:04.505363 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 1338] [client 66.249.64.17:47360] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Apr 09 11:34:29.890432 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 30349] [client 60.10.114.129:4892] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Apr 09 12:21:16.013396 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 30351] [client 66.249.64.147:61628] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Apr 09 13:16:44.877416 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 30348] [client 66.249.64.18:48720] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Apr 09 13:28:05.782783 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 31639] [client 54.67.59.131:47628] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Apr 09 15:59:59.764704 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 30349] [client 66.102.6.116:50307] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Apr 09 20:48:48.419540 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 30349] [client 211.23.154.138:44382] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Apr 09 20:49:19.596952 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 30790] [client 146.185.223.240:61291] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Apr 09 20:49:25.365282 2018] [:error] [pid 32239] [client 146.185.223.240:53694] script '/var/www/html/xmlrpc.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Apr 09 20:49:30.881307 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 1338] [client 146.185.223.240:57697] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Apr 09 21:59:59.860423 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 30790] [client 52.41.211.72:54578] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Apr 09 22:40:17.025377 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 32239] [client 66.102.6.118:63371] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Mon Apr 09 23:54:26.754931 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 30350] [client 141.8.142.139:44732] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Tue Apr 10 02:04:12.364159 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 30350] [client 66.249.64.17:46304] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Tue Apr 10 04:31:13.380666 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 30349] [client 66.249.79.21:45988] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Tue Apr 10 05:11:35.587141 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 32239] [client 66.249.79.19:52379] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Tue Apr 10 05:41:26.176137 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 1338] [client 66.102.6.118:51864] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Tue Apr 10 05:57:36.520454 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 30347] [client 66.249.79.110:36194] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Tue Apr 10 12:44:25.251573 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 32239] [client 52.34.24.33:60587] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Tue Apr 10 13:08:39.896323 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 1338] [client 141.8.142.139:53710] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Tue Apr 10 13:31:14.603115 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 30790] [client 180.234.211.210:44472] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Tue Apr 10 13:42:16.181640 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 30351] [client 107.170.192.57:54176] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Tue Apr 10 16:31:20.752769 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 30349] [client 196.52.43.109:6666] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Tue Apr 10 17:43:24.572519 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 1338] [client 66.102.6.118:64283] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Tue Apr 10 23:32:45.653283 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20339] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
(13)Permission denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /var/www/example2.com/error.log.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
(13)Permission denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /var/www/example2.com/error.log.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
(13)Permission denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /var/www/example2.com/error.log.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
(13)Permission denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /var/www/example2.com/error.log.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
(13)Permission denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /var/www/example2.com/error.log.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
(13)Permission denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /var/www/example2.com/error.log.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
(13)Permission denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /var/www/example2.com/error.log.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
(13)Permission denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /var/www/example2.com/error.log.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
(13)Permission denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /var/www/example2.com/error.log.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
(13)Permission denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /var/www/example2.com/error.log.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

Answer (score 0):

The first Message `httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE` tells that the Service couldn't even be started.
The next Message `kill[11116]: kill: cannot find process ""` wants to say that the Service Process couldn't be killed because it couldn't be started before.

According to the Log Messages from `/var/log/httpd/error_log` the Service stopped because of a Problem with your VirtualHost Definitions

```
(13)Permission denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /var/www/example2.com/error.log.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

If the Service cannot write into the configured Log Files because

- The Directory does not exist
- The Harddisk is readonly
- The Harddisk is full

the Service cannot be started.

We will have to see the VirtualHost Configuration of `example2.com`, too.

I suspect that something is happening to your Service Configuration because on one hand the Log says that the DocumentRoot is at `/var/www/html/`
But than it wants to write the Logs at `/var/www/example2.com/`

Comment: Well you wouldn't want to write server logs to something underneath `DocumentRoot` anyway. Another possible cause is that `/var/www/example2.com` lacks the neccessary SElinux magic to allow the server to write there. (Check `getenforce` to see if SELinux is enabled.)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz  /usr/sbin/sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      28

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz, @moon For Servers with SELinux enabled you need to check your Log Directory with `ls -lZ` to see if has the correct `httpd_log_t` Context. Actually it could have the wrong SELinux Context if you copied the Web Project from your Home Directory.

Comment: @BodoHugoBarwich In `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` DocumentRoot is `/var/www/html`

Comment: @BodoHugoBarwich And configuration of example.com is

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

Comment: configuration file is `/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/example.com.conf`

Comment: Probably `${APACHE_LOG_DIR}` does not have the correct value so that the Service wants to write to `/var/www/example2.com/`. My advice would be to create a Directory `/var/www/example.com/logs` and change the Configuration to `ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log CustomLog /var/www/example.com/logs/access.log`

Comment: @moon As I understand from the Configuration File the Intention is that all Web Projects on the Web Server write to the same Global Log File. So those Log Entries `[pid 30790] [client 146.185.223.240:61291] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[pid 32239] [client 146.185.223.240:53694] script '/var/www/html/xmlrpc.php' not found` are certainly from other Web Projects that were running on the Server before you started to set up the New Web Project `example2.com`.

Comment: @BodoHugoBarwich  yes, there is another web project running on that server. I put that before virtual host step and located in `/var/www/html`. Now I don't need that when I am successful in virtual host.

Comment: For Multi-Domain Web Servers I usual use a Setup as I suggested in the previous comment. I advise you to try it for your Server as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment the line in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf :

```
#LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
```

and uncomment the line:

```
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
```